# RVM Ruby on Rails source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm no such location

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I am trying to install Ruby on rails with RVM on Ubuntu, but When I run this command:

```
 source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

I get this error:

```
bash: /home/user/.rvm/scripts/rvm: No such file or directory
```

I tried to:

```
gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys D39DC0E3
```

and

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

It didn't help. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please, try:

```
$ gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3
```

and

```
$\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

From http://rvm.io/